# Does Apache's active and idle connections contribute to MaxClients?

Tags: apache

Is there a way / command that I can run to see the:

1. Active Apache workers and their total count
2. The Waiting workers not used because of their KeepAlive timeout value (TIME_WAIT???)
3. The total number of queued visitors due to Apache having reached the MaxClients limit?
4. Any indication of whether queuing is happening, or if my MaxClients setting is in order.
5. Is the Apache MaxClients setting the total of the active and idle Apache processes, or just active?

We currently have a server that seems to be hitting the MaxClients, but not with active connections but with the waiting connections as well. Is this possible?

Thank a million

Answer (score 0):

Possibly mod_status is what you are looking for?

http://www.apache.org/server-status